# OnDeserialized attribute for ProtoBuf-NET

Tags: protobuf-net

We used JSON.NET to serialize our data together with `OnDeserialized` attribute to execute custom code after deserialization:

```
[OnDeserialized]
internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    ...
}
```

Now we try to use `protobuf` instead of `JSON.NET` and this method is not executing. Is there another way to achieve this behaviour with `protobuf.net`?

Here is an example that doesn't work:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof (Profile), false).Add(1000, "Id").Add(1001, "Text");

        var test = new Profile {Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Text = "123"};

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, test);

            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var deserialized =  Serializer.Deserialize<Profile>(memoryStream);

            Console.WriteLine(deserialized.Text); // should output "changed"
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Profile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Text = "changed";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnDeserializedMethod");
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Bar { get;set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo { Bar = "abc" };
        var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(foo);
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Bar);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
OnDeserializedMethod
abc
```

Can you be more specific? Perhaps showing a complete example that reproduces what you are seeing? Also: are you *sure* you are using protobuf-net? Some people get very confused between protobuf-net and protobuf-csharp-port. I cannot comment on what features the latter supports.

Comment: Hi Marc! Your example works, but my code still not working. I added a sample console app to my question to demonstrate this.

Comment: @user in the example, you have disabled automatic configuration (the false). Because of this, automatic configuration didn't happen! If you are manually configuring the model, that includes telling it what callbacks to invoke. There is a method on the MetaType for that. Or just pass true instead.

Comment: Thank you Marc! I have changed the second parameter to true and it works now.