# Deserialize Binary Data of Object Array as Elements Are Available

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, stream

I've been sifting through the posts and forums but could not find a way to achieve this.

I have an array of 10,000,000 Person objects. I'm sending these objects over the network using a Streamed WCF Net.Tcp web service.

The problem is I want to read the first, for example, 5000 Person objects of the array as is it arrives and process only those. Afterwhich I will advance the stream and read another 5000, etc...

I haven't been able to find a way to do this because as far as I can tell there is no explicit size of objects in C#. As in, I can't just read the first 312 Bytes of the stream and say "Yes this is the first Person object. Now read the next 312 Bytes to get the next person.".

I ideally would like to use **ProtoBuf-Net** to serialize my objects but the .NET **BinaryFormatter** is fine as well.

I'm also open to sending the data in chunks, such as arrays of 5000. But I want to do so without opening a brand new tcp connection everytime. If only there was a way to tell the code that reads the stream: "Ok, deserialize everything I just sent you (Array of 5000) and then I will continue writing another 5000 to the stream".

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: With Net library you have to read all the available data and store it in a temporary buffer (byte array in your case).  If a record is 312 bytes you wait until the temporary buffer has more than 312 bytes and then process the 312 bytes.  Then remove the 312 bytes from temporary buffer and wait until you get the next 312 bytes.

Comment: What if my object has a string property. Wouldn't the size of each object differ?

Comment: You have binary data which is not like the c# classes with variable sizes. Any object must have a method for determining the size.  It can be preceded by a length variable, have a fixed size or a termination character.  If you are sending a class object in c# on TCP the serialize method will create a byte array which you can determine the size.  Then add the size count to beginning of data.  On receive side read the byte count and then read put the data into byte array and deserialize the byte array.  This will work provided the serialize classes on tx have same structure as classes on rx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may not be an explicit size for most objects in .NET but you can find the size of a serialized object. First send the size (in bytes) of the serialized object, then send the serialized object.

```
// psuedo-code
byte[] serializedObj = DoSerialization(Person);    // we see length on an array

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
    writer.Write(serializedObj.Length);
    stream.Write(serializedObj);
}
```

You can also do this in bulk by modifying what and how you send your objects. You could create a `List<Person>`, add N number of `Person`, serialize the List and send as before.

Although I am not sure if sending the size before sending the data is necessary, it can help when you are reading the stream, to know how many bytes you are expecting.

Comment: Very simple; Can't believe I didn't think of it. I programmed the receiving end to read 4 bytes for the length, then read the length.. It will do this until the end of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with protobuf-net simply by using a `ObservableCollection<Person>` in your receiving system.  When the collection grows larger than 5000 objects during deserialization, remove and processing the items in an [`ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) callback.  Then process any remaining items in an [`[OnDeserialized]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855199/ondeserialized-attribute-for-protobuf-net) callback.

For instance, consider the following root object:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class RootObject
{
    public RootObject()
    {
        this.People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<StreamingContext>> OnDeserialized;

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        var onDeserialized = OnDeserialized;
        if (onDeserialized != null)
            onDeserialized(this, new EventArgs<StreamingContext> { Value = context });
    }
}

public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Say you have a method you would like to call to process each 5000 `Person` objects as they are added to the collection, for instance:

```
const int ProcessIncrement = 5000;

void ProcessItems(ICollection<Person> people, bool force)
{
    if (people == null || people.Count == 0)
        return;
    if (people.Count >= ProcessIncrement || force)
    {
        // Remove and process the items, possibly on a different thread.
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Processing {0} people." people.Count));
        people.Clear();
    }
}
```

You can pre-allocate your `RootObject` and add listeners with the necessary logic, and merge contents of the serialization stream into the root:

```
// Allocate a new RootObject
var newRoot = new RootObject();

// Add listeners to process chunks of Person objects as they are added
newRoot.People.CollectionChanged += (o, e) =>
    {
        // Process each chunk of 5000.
        var collection = (ICollection<Person>)o;
        ProcessItems(collection, false);
    };

newRoot.OnDeserialized += (o, e) =>
    {
        // Forcibly process any remaining no matter how many.
        ProcessItems(((RootObject)o).People, true);
    };

// Deserialize from the stream onto the pre-allocated newRoot
Serializer.Merge(stream, newRoot);
```

As required, `ProcessItems` will be called every time an object is added to the collection, processing them in increments of 5000 then processing the remainder unconditionally.

Now, the only question is, does protobuf-net load the entire stream into memory before deserializing the collection, or does it do streaming deserialization?  As it turns out, it does the latter, as shown by this [sample fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jwTe01) that shows the stream position being gradually incremented as the items in the `People` collection are added, processed and removed.

Here I added the listeners to `RootObject` manually before deserialization.  If you were to add them in the constructor itself, you could use `ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(Stream stream)` instead of `Serializer.Merge` onto a pre-allocated root object, which might be easier to integrate into your current architecture.

Incidentally, this technique should work with `XmlSerializer` and Json.NET as well.

Comment: This is great for creating a data structure that will automatically write my objects to the stream as a certain count is reached. But as far as I can tell it doesn't solve my problem in the question: How to deserialize the Person objects on the receiving end, 5000 at a time. Sean's solution actually worked for me so I think I'm going to use that for my issue. But I will definitely use your structure as a baseline to create my own process that will feed the stream. Thanks alot!